# need to select all yes/no radio buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I was trying to select all yes radio buttons when click on select all, i mean if you click on "yes" and then click on select all must select all fields as yes the same behavior for "no" radio button.
Also i was trying with check-boxes but not sure which is the best ways to achieve it.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('bValidation[]');
    for(var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

```
            <input type="checkbox" name="bValidation" value="Y"> Y
            <input type="checkbox" name="bValidation" value="N"> N
            <br><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Select All
```

Comment: Where is the radio buttons ?

Comment: `bValidation[]` != `bValidation`

Comment: These aren't Radio buttons - they are Checkboxes. Only one Radio button can be selected at any one time. To select (check) Checkboxes, set Checkbox.checked to True.

Answer (score 3):

Change this `'bValidation[]'` to this `'bValidation'`

```js
function selectAll(source) {
  checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('bValidation');
  for (var i in checkboxes)
    checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="bValidation" value="Y"> Y
<input type="checkbox" name="bValidation" value="N"> N
<br><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Select All
```

Comment: it works, but what im trying is that all radio buttons with Y value will selected after click on select Y and then select all and vice-versa for N

Comment: They are not radiobuttons, they are checkboxes.

Comment: sorry, checkboxes... when i click on select all, all checkboxes are selected and i need to click on Y and after select all and all checkboxes with Y value must be selected. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

instead of writing just name in input type, you have to specify  name="bValidation[]" in both inputs.

```js
function selectAll(source) {
    checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('bValidation[]');
    for(var i in checkboxes)
        checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="bValidation[]" value="Y"> Y
<input type="checkbox" name="bValidation[]" value="N"> N
<br><input type="checkbox" id="selectall" onClick="selectAll(this)" />Select All
```